# Cordova 6 app cannot load from file:// path

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

I have updated an existing app to Cordova 6.0.0 and am having problems running it on an iOS device with XCode 7.2.1 targeting iOS 9.

I have installed the WKWebView plugin: `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine 1.0.2`

When running the app, which is built with AngularJS, one of the first things it tries to do is open a json file:

```
$http.get('data/config.json').success(function(data) {
  // do stuff
});
```

But we get this error in the web view console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/
E9D74C94-ADC6-410F-9F41-7CE63CB7877F/Milk.app/www/data/config.json. Cross 
origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

In the config.xml file we have:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
```

Why is the **file://** request being blocked like this and how can I fix it?

*edit*

According to the [plugin page](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine):

> "In iOS 9, Apple has fixed the issue present through iOS 8 where you
>   cannot load locale files using file://, and must resort to using a
>   local webserver. However, you are still not able to use XHR from the
>   file:// protocol without CORS enabled on your server."

What do they mean by *"your server"*? What server? We are loading a local file, there is no server!

Comment: which ios version is used?

Comment: @Meiko it's iOS 9. Given that the issue where a local web server is apparently *fixed* for iOS 9, I don't understand the part about enabling CORS on the local server. In other words it sounds like it's not actually fixed!

Comment: If you are using Cordova 6 and cordova-ios@4.0, then you don't need this plugin, Cordova uses the wkwebview: http://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/01/28/tools-release.html

Comment: @Joerg - OK, good to know. However removing the plugin did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Joerg, you are wrong. cordova-ios 4.0 doesn't use wkwebview, just add support to plugable webviews, like wkwebview, but to use it, he has to install the plugin as he did.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDIT:

The ionic team has been working on a fork of the WKWebViewEngine plugin and has fixed some of the XHR issues, not sure if this one is fixed. You can take a look on https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Old answer:
This is a known issue, local `file://` url `XmlHttpRequests` are not allowed in `WKWebViewEngine` (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10143)

For more known issues see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10237?jql=labels%20%3D%20wkwebview-known-issues

If you want to make local ajax call to work you should use the `wkwebview-engine-localhost` plugin (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugins/tree/master/wkwebview-engine-localhost)

Or Telerik's `WKWebView` plugin (https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/WKWebView).

Both of them will use a local webserver that solves some of the known WKWebView limitations.

Comment: Interesting. Without the Polyfill Plugin Cordova 6 (cordova-ios 4) is essentially not ready for use in a lot of cases.

Comment: cordova-ios 4 is fully usable, but with the UIWebView. WKWebView isn't usable in most cases because of apple bugs, so let's hope the fix them on iOS 10. Anyway, in most cases UIWebView is good enough, most people won't need WKWebView

Comment: OK, I thought that the UIWebView had been replaced in cordova-ios 4.

Comment: No, if you don't install cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine it will use UIWebView, and it uses UIWebView on iOS 8

Answer (score 9):

Add these lines on your config.xml file.  That solved my problem of reading local files.

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
</platform>
```

Comment: In versions of Cordova 6+ (2020 and beyond) this is the way.

Answer (score 1):

I was having problems with local file access as well including SQLite access. I created a plugin based on some sample code I found, modified it to get it working and it appears to work great now. YMMV

https://github.com/TheMattRay/cordova-plugin-wkwebviewxhrfix

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using [Oracle's plugin](https://github.com/oracle/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-file-xhr)

Comment: Did you create a request? i'm trying to access local png file.